# awk's record ranges: last field of the line is ignored?

Tags: awk

if I have a file with:

```
0
on
0
off
0
0
...
```

the command:

```
awk '$1 == "on", $1 == "off"' < file
```

returns nothing.
Curiously, if I change my input file to:

```
0
on ;
0
off ;
0
0
```

the returned value is as expected:

```
on ;
0
off ;
```

What happens here? It seems as if awk does not like it if my fields are the last of a line.
I tried to change `$1` for `$0` and also `$0 == "on"` for `$0 == "on\n"` with no more success.

Is there a way to deal with awk's record ranges that are the last field of a record?

Reference: [This page of the awk manual](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_51.html#SEC54)

Comment: oh, it's hard to understand your example.

Comment: @AvinashRaj is it still unclear after reading the webpage linked? It is very short

Comment: yes, it returns correctly the above expected output. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AvinashRaj did you try it without the semicolumns as well? I want the output without the semicolumns. I added them just to see if it would work better and it does.

Comment: yes, it works for me without adding the semicolon.

Comment: hmmm, must be a stupid thing with awk's settings then, but I have no idea which

Comment: Mary, it works for me (without semicolons, I mean) using two different implementations, namely `gawk` and `mawk`. OTOH you reference the `nawk` manual, are you by any chance using `nawk`?

Comment: Are you sure there are no funny non-printable characters somewhere?

Comment: @joepd: I am using notepad++, if I set the preferences to View>Show all characters, my lines end with `CR` `LF`, I think that means a lineskip no?

Comment: @Mary Use `cat -v file` to check for non-printable characters.Also try running `dos2unix` on the file and try your awk again. It is likely that the carriage return is being seen as part of the string , similarly `awk '$1~"on", $1~"off"' `should work if my presumptions are correct.

Comment: @gboffi my `awk --version` is `GNU Awk 3.1.7` I think it's gawk then.
@Jidder all the non-printable charaters I get are `^M`

Comment: @Jidder: I do not have the `dos2unix` command available on my machine :( Your wavelet thing does fix the problem though, so does AvinashRaj's solution in the comments of his answer below

Comment: If you are on Windows, using Windows-style line endings (which is what you have) shouldn't be an issue (so you shouldn't need to use `dos2unix`, which converts line endings to Unix-style ones).

Comment: you can use `sed -ie "s/\r//" file` if you do not have dos2unix for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
awk '...' < file
```

you are passing the file to awk via the standard input stream. This is different to doing

```
awk '...' file
```

which passes the name of the file to awk for it to open. Normally, these two approaches are equivalent. However an issue arises on Windows due to the difference in line endings.

This example demonstrates the problem:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)print NR, i, "|"$i"|"}'  < file.txt
| 1 |0
| 1 |on
| 1 |0
| 1 |off
| 1 |0
6 1 |0|
```

Compare the output to this:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)print NR, i, "|"$i"|"}' file.txt
1 1 |0|
2 1 |on|
3 1 |0|
4 1 |off|
5 1 |0|
6 1 |0|
```

The output of the second test is the expected one. The issue is that the carriage return `\r` is interpreted as part of the record in the first case.

On GNU awk, a multi-character record separator can be specified, which allows you to pass the contents of the file via standard input:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)print NR, i, "|"$i"|"}' RS='\r\n' < file.txt
1 1 |0|
2 1 |on|
3 1 |0|
4 1 |off|
5 1 |0|
6 1 |0|
```

Answer (score 1):

You have control-Ms in your input file, remove them with dos2unix or similar before running your command.

Also - it's never useful to use range expressions as they make the trivial things slightly briefer but then anything even marginally more complicated (e.g. not printing the start and/or end lines) causes you to write duplicate code or do a complete re-write. Just use a flag:

```
awk '$1 == "on"{f=1} f; $1 == "off"{f=0}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below awk command,

```
$ awk '$1 == "on", $1 == "off"' file
on
0
off
```

**OR**

```
awk -v RS="[\n\r]+" '$1 == "on", $1 == "off"' file
```

There maybe a chance of carriage return `\r` would exists in the input file. So set the Record separator as `[\n\r]+`. This regex would assign one or more newline or carriage return chars as value to Record separator variable.

Comment: with the dollar sign at the beginning?

Comment: @TomFenech I think they he left out the `<`, it should work either way though

Comment: i think this would help. `awk -v RS="[\n\r]+" '$1 == "on", $1 == "off"' file`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: you win! How is that? I don't get it

Comment: Yes, this does solve the problem on my windows system using git bash (I get no output if the file is redirected). @Mary you shouldn't be using `<` to redirect the file into awk. I didn't think that it would cause a problem but apparently it does.

Comment: @TomFenech _Maybe_ when `gawk` reads stdin it just reads the byte stream and all the eventual spurious stuff, but when it reads from file it knows it better, maybe platform-wise...

Comment: @TomFenech do you have an example of `<` not working ?

Comment: @Jidder yes, I was able to reproduce the problem on my machine running Windows, which I have shown in my answer.